# How to use webhook on Azure App service in Single Container mode

Tags: azure, docker

I created Azure App Service. I choosed "single container" and used "Private Registry".

I filled my private docker hub, credentials, username & password and my site is running my docker image website well.

Now I want to use NEW image with newer tag. I noticed, there is a "webhook" functionality but I dont know how to use this webhook. I thing, that this webhook can be used to pull newer image from my registry but I dont know how to use it.

If this is not the meaning of this web hook, what is the best practise to PULL new container to web app service.

**Note:** I am not using Azure Container registry. I have my own private hub. And I want to use Jenkins to deploy new container.

[image]